# Rails 3 route appends _index to route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am migrating a Rails 2.3.8 version to Rails 3.0 and so ive rewritten my routes file. When i list the routes using `rake routes`, i see some route names have `_index` appended to them. I cant figure out why this is.

Relevant routes:

Rails 2.3.8:

```
map.namespace "tracker", :path_prefix => "" do |planner|
    planner.resources :planner, :collection => {:step1 => :get,
                                                :add => :get,
                                                :unsubscribe => [:get, :post] }
end
```

Rails 3.0 route:

```
namespace "tracker", :path => "" do
  resources :planner do
    collection do
      get :step1
      get :add
      get :unsubscribe
      post :unsubscribe
    end
  end
end
```

Output from `rake routes`

Rails 2.3.8

```
step1_tracker_planner        GET    /planner/step1(.:format)
add_tracker_planner          GET    /planner/add(.:format)
unsubscribe_tracker_planner  GET    /planner/unsubscribe(.:format)
                             POST   /planner/unsubscribe(.:format)
```

Rails 3.0

```
step1_tracker_planner_index       GET    /planner/step1(.:format)
add_tracker_planner_index         GET    /planner/add(.:format)
unsubscribe_tracker_planner_index GET    /planner/unsubscribe(.:format)
                                  POST   /planner/unsubscribe(.:format)
```

Any ideas as to why this `_index` is being added would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is because your resource is named `:planner` instead of `:planners` that Rails decided to add the _index to any collection nested underneath. My guess it is there for readability.

The action named in the collection normally translates to a verb, so I can see why this makes sense. Take the typical photos resource example given in the routing docs:

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end

search_photos GET    /photos/search(.:format)
```

But if instead we called the resources 'photo'...

```
resources :photo do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end

search_photo_index GET    /photo/search(.:format)
```

In the first case, you search the "photos", and in the second case you search the "photo index".

Comment: Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: You can use the word "resource" (singular) instead of "resources" in your routes file.

This will generate similar routes as a "resources" request, with the exception of the :index route.  Since Rails assumes you're working with a singular object, it's not automatically generating an index because you wouldn't have a list of items, you would only have one.

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Answer (score 10):

You should be using either `resource :planner` either `resources :planners` depending on what you need. To learn about singular resource and it differences check out [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: what if your model is the same in singular and plural (e.g., series)? It seems to add _index there even though it is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Semyon Perepelitsa's response, note that `resource :planner` expects the controller's name is `PlannersController`, whereas `resources :planners` expects `PlannerController`.

If you don't want to rename your controller when changing from resources to resource, you can override the default by specifying `resource :planner, controller: :planner`.