# Using generated paths with resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I have following routes defined:

```
CyberTrackRails3::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|de|nl/ do
    resources :login do
      get 'index', on: :collection
      get 'check', on: :collection
    end
  end
end
```

Now, url_for(:controller => 'login', :action => 'check'), gives me the correct url, en/login/check.

Using login_check_path however doesn't work. How do I make this work?

I've tried replacing **get 'index', on: :collection** with **match 'check' => 'check'** but that doesn't work. Neither does **match 'check' => 'login#check'**.

Comment: did you look at output of rake routes  command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're adding an action to a resource, i think the automatically generated name is going to be reversed, ie 'check_logins_path' (see [adding-more-restful-actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions))

do you need login_check_path specifically? if so, you should be able to define the path outside of the resources :login block, ie

```
match '/login/check' => 'login#check', :via => :get, :as => 'login_check'
```

and like Fivell suggested, `rake routes` will show you the automatically generated name for a route.

Comment: Is it also possible to add the :post in the same line?

Comment: as in accept GET or POST requests? `:via => [:get, :post]` should do the trick - [http-verb-constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints). in the match pattern above, you'd just need to switch the via parameter, if you wanted to do it in your original code, i think you'd switch the line in the resources :login block to `match 'check', :on => :collection, :via => [:get, :post]`

Comment: also fwiw, the automatically generated named route for the code in your question looks to be 'check_login_index_path'. the '_index' part has to do with using a singular resource (login vs logins). more info on that here - [rails-3-route-appends-index-to-route-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476763/rails-3-route-appends-index-to-route-name)