# Rails 3 route appends _index to route name even if resource is plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following routes:

**routes.rb:**

```
  namespace :admin do
    #...
    resources :carousel_images
  end
```

**controller:**

```
def new
    @admin_carousel_image = CarouselImages.new
    #...
```

In view, I `render 'form'` :

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @admin_carousel_image] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**The model:**

```
class Admin::CarouselImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  mount_uploader :image, CarouselUploader
end
```

When I visit `/admin/carousel_images/new`, I get

> ### NoMethodError in Admin/carousel_images#new
>
> Showing
>   /home/pinouchon/code/sharewizz/webapp/app/views/admin/carousel_images/_form.html.erb
>   where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method `admin_carousel_images_index_path' for
>   #<#:0xdfe45a4>

I tought that "_index" in the path [wasn't appended when the resource is plural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476763/rails-3-route-appends-index-to-route-name). Why is it appended in my case ?

Comment: Does the fact the model name is plural or not matters ?

Answer (score 0):

Rails occasionally cannot figure out how to pluralize or detect a plural. Have you tried inflectors? I had a similar case and worked for me.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'carousel_image', 'carousel_images'
end
```

BTW, I am using Rails 5.1.

Answer (score -1):

Change the following and try:

```
def new
  @admin_carousel_image = Admin::CarouselImage.new #CarouselImage is your model name here. It should be singular.
  #...
end
```

In the View, if you are rendering your `form` from the `index.html.erb`,

you should have the following:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

The `index` file should be in the order of `app/view/admin/carousel_images/index`

Here the route file find the index.html.erb in carousel_images folder and render the form.