# Android HTTP post request being interpreted as a GET request on the ruby server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

I'm sending JSON as a POST to a ruby app on Heroku server (from Android app). As the post title says, the Heroku logs output:

```
Started GET "/app_session" for 62.40.34.220 at 2013-05-20 22:12:22 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/app_session"):
```

This is the Android request:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                    httppost.setEntity(se);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(temp);
```

Here is the routes file:

```
resources :app_session, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

And the `rake routes` output:

```
app_session_index POST   /app_session(.:format)         app_session#create
      app_session DELETE /app_session/:id(.:format)     app_session#destroy
```

What's going on here? Why is `_index` added to `app_session`? 
Surely this is the problem...

Comment: If you do the same POST using curl, what do you get? This might help you narrow this down to a rails issue or a client side issue in your android code.

Comment: I haven't used curl yet, but I just ran a snippet I found and got back a 301 status code (Moved Permanently). Content-Length: 0 is also in the response. Is this helpful to my cause?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your resource is not plural. See [Rails 3 route appends _index to route name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476763/rails-3-route-appends-index-to-route-name) for more.

You should be good to go if you change the route to:

`resources :app_sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]`

Comment: Of course! Thanks, it fixed my routes. Output is now: 'app_sessions POST   /app_sessions(.:format)        app_sessions#create
     app_session DELETE /app_sessions/:id(.:format)    app_sessions#destroy'
     However it still appears to be a GET request on the server.