# index_ appended to path erroneously added to rails 4 route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I added a controller named "Triage" to my application, and added a PUT route as follows:

```
resources :triage do
  collection do
    put :process_multiple
  end
end
```

Instead of the expected process_multiple_triage_path route, it seems it is processed as `process_multiple_triage_index_path`:

```
process_multiple_triage_index_path   PUT     /triage/process_multiple(.:format) triage#process_multiple
triage_index_path    GET     /triage(.:format)   triage#index
POST     /triage(.:format)   triage#create
```

Answer: Turns out it is because triage is seen as a singular resource by Rails, thus by way of convention, you'd request the "index" of the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because of the singular form of triage. Rails noticed that triage was used, instead of triages, and thus as a result of convention, the request would be of the index. I've linked below another StackOverflow that explains this well.

You can use `resource :triage` instead of `resources` (which also won't create an index route automatically either)

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476763/rails-3-route-appends-index-to-route-name)

Answer (score 0):

It's on the collecion, so Rails appends an _index. If you want to overwrite it, just change to:

```
resources :triage do
  collection do
    put :process_multiple, as: :proccess_multiple_triage
  end
end
```

And now you'll be able to use `process_multiple_triage_path`

Comment: So any routes added on in the collection adds _index? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Note: I updated my routes to `put :process_multiple, as: :process_multiple` and still the route is process_multiple_triage_triage_index_path